# calculate duplicate average python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, pandas

I have a 2D array:

```
 [[2,1],[2,32],[4,4512],[1,34],[2,323],[2,42],[1,23],[4,123]...]
```

finally, I want to calculate the mean and get the array like [ [1,mean],[2,mean],[3,mean]...],

does anyone have a good solution? I used:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    temp =[]
    for j in range(len(array)):
        if Table[i][0] == Table[j][0]:
                temp.append(Table[j])
```

then calculate the mean of `temp`, but it's not quit efficient.

is there anyone has the solution by using `pandas` library?

Comment: Can you give value of `mean`  in `[ [1,mean],[2,mean],[3,mean]..]`?

Comment: @Slslam like [1,(34+23)/2],[2,(1+32+323+42)/4,...] from the current example array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas and groupby:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1],[2,32],[4,4512],[1,34],[2,323],[2,42],[1,23],[4,123]])
df.groupby(0).mean()

        1
0        
1    28.5
2    99.5
4  2317.5
```

Comment: But this return a pandas variable, how to assign it back to numpy variable

Answer (score 5):

You should create a dictionary, collecting all the values (second items) for each of the keys (first item). You can then calculate the mean for each entry in the dictionary.

```
from __future__ import division # use floating-point division by default
values = [[2,1],[2,32],[4,4512],[1,34],[2,323],[2,42],[1,23],[4,123]]

values_by_key = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in values:
    values_by_key[k].append(v)
means = sorted([(k, sum(v) / len(v)) for k, v in values_by_key.items()])
```

Or, you could use `groupby` to group items with equal key (remember to sort first) and use a (somewhat complicated) nested list comprehension.

```
means = [(k, sum(v)/len(v)) 
         for k, v in ((k, [v[1] for v in vals]) 
                      for k, vals in itertools.groupby(sorted(values), key=lambda t: t[0]))]
```

In both cases, `means` ends up as `[(1, 28.5), (2, 99.5), (4, 2317.5)]`. Compexity should be *O(nlogn)* (for the sorting; if sorted output is not required, than complexity for the first approach, using a dict, is just *O(n)*).

Personally, I would go with the dictionary approach. While the other can be done in "one line", the dict is much clearer and also faster (even if sorting is required, since in this case the sort is done after the merging, i.e. with fewer elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a functional style to solve this problem

```
data = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5], ...]

def make_filter(n):
  def filter_n(d):
    return d[0] == n
  return filter_n

def calculate(n, data):
  data_n = filter(make_filter(n), data)
  s = reduce(lambda acc, d: acc + d[1], data_n, 0)
  n = len(data_n)
  if n > 0:
    return float(s) / n
  else:
    raise Exception
```

Then you call `calculate` function and should substitute the `Exception` for a suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Counter` and `defaultdict` for faster performance as below-

```
from collections import Counter,defaultdict

sm = defaultdict(float)

data = [[2,1],[2,32],[4,4512],[1,34],[2,323],[2,42],[1,23],[4,123]]

#generate sum of second elements for all the keys (first elements)
for i in data:
    sm[i[0]]+=i[1]

#Count the occurrances of the keys (first occurrances)
c = Counter([i[0] for i in data])

#Produce data
print [[k,sm[k]/c[k]]for k in sm.keys()]
```

Output-

```
[[1, 28.5], [2, 99.5], [4, 2317.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: replaced reduce by sum

You can use built-in map and reduce functions:

```
from __future__ import division
array = [[2,1],[2,32],[4,4512],[1,34],[2,323],[2,42],[1,23],[4,123]]
d = dict()
l = list() # result
map(lambda i:(d.setdefault(i[0],[]).append(i[1])), array)
map(lambda key: l.append([key, sum(d[key])/len(d[key])]), d.iterkeys())
print(l)
```

You'll get:

```
[[1, 28.5], [2, 99.5], [4, 2317.5]]
```

Explanation:
First you have to group all values by key (in your case key is the first value of nested array).
Second you have to calculate mean and create resulting array.

Comment: You should not use `map` for side effects! This code will not work with `Python 3`, because then `map` is a generator, and those `lambda`s will only be executed once the generator is consumed. Instead of the first `map`, a regular `for` loop would be better. For the second `map`, just create `l` with a list comprehension. Also, that `reduce` can be replaced by `sum`.

Comment: Yes, you are right about Python 3, but this question has python-2.7 tag.

Comment: Well, it is still bad practice to use `map` for sideeffects and throw away the actual result. Why not use the result directly? `l = map(lambda key: [key, sum(d[key])/len(d[key])], d)` Or as a list comprehension: `l = [[key, sum(d[key])/len(d[key])] for key in d]`